# Feed data from parameterized trigger step into execute shell step

Tags: jenkins

I have a requirement to Serverspec test a Cloudformation stack that is created by a Jenkins job called "Create_Stack".

A second Jenkins job will call the existing Create_Stack job via a [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), and then in a subsequent Execute Shell step execute the Serverspec test suite.

However, in order to do that, the Execute Shell step needs to know the Cloudformation Stack Name.

At the moment, the Stack Name exists as an Environment Variable in the Create_Stack job, and it also exists in the archived artifact file containing the returned output from the `aws cloudformation create-stack` command.

I have considered looking up Stack Name in the artifact file in `$WORKSPACE/../../Create_Stack/workspace/my-stack-output.json`.  This isn't ideal as it's awkward, and also vulnerable to a race condition if someone were to run this job again immediately while my test was running.

Is there a clean way to make the Stack Name available to subsequent Execute Shell build steps?

Comment: This isn't really a serverspec question.

Comment: Thanks, OK, updated.

Comment: What version of Jenkins do you have? Because if you're using latest Jenkins (2.x) then you might be affected by this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2016-05-11

Comment: I'm using Jenkins 1.651, according to the RPM version string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I figured out that the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) can be used to solve this problem.